# SASS for loop to output increments of 15

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, gulp-sass

I am trying to output the following:

```
.time15 {
    width: 25%;
}
.time30 {
    width: 50%;
}
.time45 {
    width: 75%;
}
.time60 {
    width: 100%;
}
.time75 {
    width: 125%;
}
```

All the way up to .time1440

Here is my code:

```
$max: 60 * 24;
$step: 15;

@for $i from 15 through ceil($max/$step) {
    $value: ($i - 1)*$step + 1;
    $width: $value / 60 * 100;
    .time{$value} {
        width: $value%
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following syntax error though when trying to compile:

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...   &.time{$value": expected ":", was "} {"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that SCSS can't handle the following line:

```
width: $value%;
```

It is safer to do

```
width: percentage($value);
```

Apart from that, I think that the interpolation of the selector is also wrong.
In my test I changed it to `.time-#{$value}` and that worked for me.

Full example:

```
$max: 60 * 24;
$step: 15;

@for $i from $step through ceil($max/$step) {
    $value: ($i - 1) * $step + 1;
    $width: $value / 60 * 100;

    .time-#{$value} {
        width: percentage($value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this maybe what you're looking for:

```
$max: 60 * 24;
$step: 15;

@for $i from 1 through ($max/$step) {
    $value: $step * $i;
    $width: $i * 25;
    .time#{$value} {
        width: $width + 0%
    }
}
```